# Play Audio on .png files Xcode

Tags: audio, png, avaudioplayer, playback

i need to play audio when one png is pressed.

I have a game, but is not in storyboard. I need the code:

-when i pressed for example, example.png , play examle.mp3, ecc.

it's possible?

Thank you

EDIT:

Here's the code.

```
- (void)playSoundEffectForMatchWithCount:(int)count
{
if (count < MIN_MATCH)
    return;

switch (count) {
    case MIN_MATCH:
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"match1.wav"];
        break;
    case (MIN_MATCH+1):
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"match2.wav"];
        break;
    case (MIN_MATCH+2):
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"match3.wav"];
        break;
    default:
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"match4.wav"];
        break;'
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use format strings for this instead of a switch with string literals. `NSString` has a method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to accomplished this would probaly to include an hidden audio tag and activate it with jquery.

Here is an example on how to control audio tags with jquery:
https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/javascriptjquery-to-control-html5-audio-elements/

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but it's for playing background audio.

Comment: EDIT: My bad! Didn't see the xcode tag! - Don't know if you can use HTML in that or not!     The audio tag should still be able to do that for you! Just use display:none; on it, and make not auto start and start it with the jquery?